# Authenticationstate Role Changes in Blazor Server

Tags: asp.net, blazor, roles, asp.net-authorization

I'm currently starting a new project in Blazor server.  I have set up the site in VS2019 and used the individual accounts authentication template.

I'm having a problem trying to understand how to enforce the site to check for the current roles assigned to the user on every page view in case the user's roles have changed.

This is my app.razor component

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
                    {
                        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/CustomLogin?ReturnURL={Uri.EscapeDataString(NavigationManager.Uri)}", true);
                    }
                
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>


            <AuthorizeView>
                <Authorized>
                    @*
                        ..do something here to make sure that the roles of the user are still correct for the component page being accessed.
                    }*@
                </Authorized>
            </AuthorizeView>


        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

The problem that I'm seeing is that if I delete a role in the aspnetuserroles table for the user in the sql database, the changes don't take effect until the user logs out and back in.

For example, the top of my usermanagement component would have a tag like this:
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "usermanagement")]

However, if I delete the usermanagement role from that user, it doesn't take effect on a page reload...only a logout and login.

My original guess was to try to do something in the Authorized tag in the app.razor above, but not sure if this is the right approach?

How exactly could I force the authenticationstateprovider to do a live check any time a new page is viewed/reloaded and not just when the user logs out?

Comment: that job should be done in your AuthenticationState class,  there you should connect to your Api that check if user is in a Role

Comment: What I read is that we should avoid creating custom authentication classes.   What I don't understand is why the built in authmanager doesn't look to the current roles that the aspnetuser is assigned to every time it draws a component but seems to cache their credentials for the entire duration of the logged in session.

Comment: No you have to create your own AuthenticationState  by inheriting from it.